# Read xml file which has 2 root node?

Tags: java, xml, dom

input file
xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <message></message>
    <messagecode></messagecode>
    <messagedescription></messagedescription>
</response>
<response>
    <message></message>
    <messagecode></messagecode>
    <messagedescription></messagedescription>
</response>
```

two response --
response id root node..
Java code

```
public void readXML(String output) {
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(output);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("response");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

            Node nNode = nodes.item(i);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) nNode;
                 NodeList msg = element.getElementsByTagName("message");
                 Element line = (Element) msg.item(i);
                 System.out.println("Message: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

                 NodeList msgcode = element.getElementsByTagName("messagecode");
                 line = (Element) msgcode.item(i);
                 System.out.println("Message Code: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

                 NodeList msgdes = element.getElementsByTagName("messagedescription");
                 line = (Element) msgdes.item(i);
                 System.out.println("Message Description: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

                 NodeList medialink = element.getElementsByTagName("medialink");
                 line = (Element) medialink.item(i);
                 System.out.println("Media link: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

                 NodeList mediastatus = element.getElementsByTagName("mediastatus");
                 line = (Element) mediastatus.item(i);
                 System.out.println("Media Status: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

            }

        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
        CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
        return cd.getData();
    }
    return "";
}
```

i try this code but error will display how can i reslove this....
SAX Exception will give error in not well formed xml file.
how can i read two root node values in same java file..

Comment: Suggest you try fixing the poorly formed XML first.

Comment: a well formed xml document must contain ONE root node.... see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling

Comment: If it has two root nodes, it's not XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML does not have matching opening/closing tags or a root node.

Something like this would suffice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<responses>
    <response>
        <message></message>
        <messagecode></messagecode>
        <messagedescription></messagedescription>
    </response>
    <response>
        <message></message>
        <messagecode></messagecode>
        <messagedescription></messagedescription>
    </response>
</responses>
```

Comment: Can you also add a Java Snippet for this? What if I want each <response> tag to be got as a Single object and map it to my Java Pojo?

Answer (score 0):

XML should always be *well-formed*, meaning that it has **only one root node** and **every opening tag should have a closing tag**. Check for correct XML syntax from W3Schools pages: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp There are also lot's of other useful information about constructing XML documents there.

If then for some reason you absolutely need to handle XML with multiple root nodes, then it's probably manual parsing with *substrings* or *regular expressions*, which i don't recommend.

Either way, if you can do something about it, try to form the XML so that you have only one root node. Period.

Comment: Alternativly, you could go with substrings or RegEx to split the two root nodes into seperate nodes and parse each structure on it's own.

Or, a totally other way to approach: Create your own root node. Go with substring actions to exclude the XML header and parse in your own root node like `<myroot><response></response><response></response></myroot>`.